# Registering a service containing <T>

Tags: mvvm-light

I have an interface/service that is defined like this

```
public interface MyAPI<T>

public class ClientAPI<T> : MyAPI<T>
```

I don't seem to be able though to register this a service using SimpleIoc. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Nope, i don't think so. SimpleIOC doesn't allow generics. You have to register each implementation of <T>.

Comment: I tried too. It seems that you can't. But you can with Unity, too bad you have to use both...